# log4j with MongoDb and best practice about saving the Log

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j

Using java and made a small test server to log incoming user connections.

Adding the MongoDb as Databas and the log4j mongo appender log4j.properties
text file configured to save the Log class to Mongo.

Everything is nice.

I can now search among all Log Collections and trace a particular user based on the "message"

I immediately thought that it could be cool to log each individual user event to respective UserData Collection Document.
Users are also stored in the mongo as a UserData class Collection.

Why i think about this is because its hard to trace user log activity if you have multiple threads all writing to the same Log Collection.

When a user loggin i wanted to attach/append the user to a new Logger and let this logger live as long as user is on the server.

Is this what the MongoDbPatternLayoutAppender is all about?
The documentations and tutorials about this is sparse maybe someone can explain?
Am i on the right track here?

What's best to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not related to MongoDB in particular...

If you're willing to try [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) you could use a [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) that does exactly what you're looking for!

For logging best practices (slf4j, log4j, LogBack, etc) you can take a look at this document [here](http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html).

Comment: been looking for some starter information for LogBack with Mongo. Only find this (http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/04/mongodb-and-recording-appenders-for.html). And it's a not for beginners. and Tomasz does not mention the SiftingAppender. Can you recommend something for a beginner.

Comment: dont think SiftingAppender are so well used with MongoDb since i cannot find any appender using them or blog's talking about them. Was Thinking about using Embedded Documents to store the Log right into eash UserData.class Document like an array of Log entry's. Can Log4j or LogBack do that btw?

Comment: Erik, I'm afraid I cannot be of much help at this point since I've never used the LogBack/Log4 together with MongoDB. I thought there was an appender ready for Mongo and that you could include the sifting functionality but apparently it's not like this...